# causes for input/output error during write on /dev/nvme0n1 on new installation of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, bootloader

Few months ago I couldn't boot ubuntu properly. I was stuck in GRUB and couln't find any file system. Booting windows didn't work either and all superblocks were bad.

My last attempt was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 again and override anything and still got **input/output error during write on /dev/nvme0n1**. I was pretty sure that the ssd was damaged.

My employer sent it back to the seller and today it came back with a report that says:

> Customer installed Linux in addition and changed boot manager. Set bootmanager to windows made device works without issues.

How can the configuration of a boot manager prevent any new os installation?

Thanks